# Powershell Running Automatically In Admin Mode

Tags: powershell, autorun

For a few days now, a Powershell window pops up, and runs in administrator mode. I have no idea why. I have tried checking if any Windows Services were edited around the date this started happening. Any ideas on how to find out what's causing this?

I'm running Win10 X64 Build 19045

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: check your short cut properties > advanced and see if "Run as Administrator" is checked. likewise go into C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell and see if powershell.exe is marked to run as admin on the Properties > Compatibility tab.